# Where can I find the source code for NVIDIA's Cg toolkit?

Tags: c++, nvidia, cg

NVIDIA's Cg toolkit is a dependency for a project I'm attempting to compile, and only has `ppc` and `x86_64` architectures on macOS. As of now, I'm currently trying to compile the software for `x86_64` and `arm64` to troubleshoot issues between the correct Intel build and an unstable M1 build.

I would have to either...

- Scrap my M1 build and build for `x86_64` with the possibility that [`Rosetta 2`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861) may go away in the near future.
- Find and compile all the dependencies for `x86_64` and `arm64` for a longer lifespan.
- Find an alternative to `Cg`.

I'm trying to stick with the 2nd option, so does NVIDIA provide source code for their very obsolete `Cg` framework? Did they used to, and if so- where? I would like to attempt to build that from source.

Comment: Considering that Cg used OpenGL on macOS you'd have a deprecation issue either way, since Apple announced their plans to remove OpenGL in a future version